# Keep getting Notice: Undefined index: media$thumbnail when trying to generate thumbnail for youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-api

Hi I keep getting an error message when trying to generate thumbnail for youtube api.  Notice: Undefined index: media$thumbnail.  Not sure what is wrong.  Here is the code.

```
 $playlist = "PL096A9A9182E4B503";
 $file = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/$playlist?v=2&alt=json");

$decoded = json_decode($file, true);

$entries = $decoded['feed']['entry'];

if (!empty($entries)) {
for($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++) {
    $parsed[$i]['thumb'] = $entries[$i]['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
    $parsed[$i]['content'] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$entries[$i]['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t']."?wmode=opaque";
  }           
}

if (!empty($parsed)){
$thumbs = array();
foreach($parsed as $entry) {
    $thumbs[]= "<a href=\"javascript:yt_load_video('".$entry['content']."');\"><img src=\"".$entry['thumb']."\"></a><br />";
  }
}
?>


  <?php if (!empty($thumbs)): ?>

  <?php foreach($thumbs as $thumb) : ?>
    <div class="video-thumbs"><?php echo $thumb ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem seems to be with this line

```
     $parsed[$i]['thumb'] = $entries[$i]['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
```

Just curious as to what is wrong and how I can fix the issue.  I would just turn off error reporting but it still returns a blank spot where the error would take place.

Comment: Can you share your $entries array?

Comment: I have reposted the code with the full code

Comment: I think it may be because the playlist has some private videos but not sure